# What's the name of the track that plays in the Power Plant?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate, game-music-identification

What's the name of the song that plays throughout the Power Plant overworld?  [As heard starting here.](https://youtu.be/61vkOjoGFGY?t=1749)

[image: screenshot of part described above]

It's a pretty catchy beat, but the track listing that usually shows up during matches doesn't show up when entering this zone.  The inaudible chatter in the background led me to think it was a Splatoon song but after listening to the SSBU Splatoon soundtracks on YT I can't seem to find anything that resembles it.  There's simply way too many tracks for me to listen through to figure out where this is from. Is it from a Megaman track since the stage seems to be staged like a Megaman level?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Checking the in game Splatoon music, it sounds like [Acid Hues](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GUyI2CuPuQ).

Comment: Thank you! I listened through about an hour of the Splatoon songs but they all had the same rock sound theme, so I assumed the remaining tracks were all the same.